# LoadVariables doesn't work as it is on Adobe website

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to learn and get used to ActionScript. I have a simple task: to use the `loadVariables();` function. I tried to use the Adobe's official reference, but as usual, the references code doesn't work as it is there. Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

function buttonClicked( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    this.createEmptyMovieClip( "variables_mc", this.getNextHighestDepth() );
    loadVariables("info.txt", variables_mc);
    trace( variables_mc.username );
}

this.myButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked );
```

I get three errors from the debugger:

```
#1 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method loadVariables.
#2 1120: Access of undefined property variables_mc.
#3 1120: Access of undefined property variables_mc.
```

**Here is the page where I have taken the code from: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000575.html**

Can anyone help me?

Thank you, and a Happy New Year!

Comment: Where is your function `loadVariables` and what is `variables_mc`?

Comment: `loadVriables` seems to be an Flash function that loads the variables from an URL, like Ajax. And `variables_mc` is a movie clip! have you read my code at list?

Comment: Yes I have, but it might not be there.

Comment: You are mixing `AS2.0` with `AS3.0`. `AS3` does not have `createEmptyMovieClip()` or `loadVariables()`.

Comment: then, can you provide me the code I need, please? seems like you know what you are talking about :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as stated in the comments `AS2.0` holds the methods `createEmptyMovieClip()` and `loadVariables()`, since `AS3.0` does not contain these global functions you'll need to use the `URL` libraries instead.

For example:

```
//declare target movieclip
var variables_mc:MovieClip;

function buttonClicked( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    variables_mc = new MovieClip();
    getVariables();
}

function getVariables():void {
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, setVariables );
    urlLoader.load( new URLRequest( "info.txt" ) );
}

function setVariables( e:Event ):void {
    //then let's say you have userName=testUser in your info.txt
    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables( e.target.data );
    variables_mc.name = urlVars.userName;
}
```

Edit: I should explain what is happening here a little, URLLoader is the actionscript class used for loading files see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

Once the file has been loaded `setVariables()` is called and URLVariables acts as a dynamic class which sets properties to the files variables. So in this case our text file contains the `userName=testUser`. `URLVariables` runs a method called `decode()` from the constructor with the parameter `e.target.data` and creates all the necessary fields. Lastly you can access them, in our case `urlVariables.userName`.

Anyway I hope this helps, I've only used this a couple of times as it is usually best to create a class that handles all this for you.